# Ubuntu Transfer data to iPod Touch

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iphone, connection, ipod-touch

What is the least fuss way of transferring data to iPod touch from ubuntu.

Preferably, I don't want to install any software. I just want to browse around the contents, add and delete as if a mass storage device.

After connecting the USB, I get a window showing "Apple, Inc. iPod", with no contents but I cant browse using nautilus :(

Even the /media/ doesn't contain an externally mounted drive.

Comment: that media folder shows your screenshots that you take by pressing the two buttons on your ipod.  (lots of help that is eh?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present, there's no non-fussy way of transferring data to iPod Touch from linux machines, Ubuntu included. There is limited support in various add-ons and media players, but these are tenous at best, and quite often work with *one* specific version of the iPhone OS.

Just to put the above in perspective, there's not much the linux community can do to improve this without Apple's help and co-operation.

Comment: Thanks, there is no non fussy way, I accept, would you know any least fussy way?

Comment: @becomingGuru: that my friend is for a totally different answer!

Comment: @becomingGuru: I gave up trying to communicate with my iPod Touch from linux a while back. The only way I know of to do this is to jailbreak the device and then transfer data via ssh. You can look at gtkpod: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gtkpod but I don't think that supports the iPhone/iPod Touch at the moment. Alternatively, iTunes on Wine, which I wouldn't recommend: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=16848.

Comment: "without Apple's help and co-operation". Actually it has to be done "against Apple's best efforts to put up hurdles".

Answer (score 2):

[Banshee Media Player (2.2.0)](http://banshee.fm/download/) provides out-of-the-box support for my 4th generation iPod Touch that works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

iFuse claims to be able to communicate with iPod Touches that are not even jailbroken

http://matt.colyer.name/projects/iphone-linux/index.php?title=Main_Page

I have jailbroken my iPod Touch 2.0 and then you can actually mount it over the network with sshfs, and with libgpod4 convince rhythmbox to transfer songs. However I needed the very unlikely combination of fresh libgpod4 with rhythmbox < 0.12 (0.11.x)

Answer (score 0):

Another way, which might very well be overkill is to run XP as a VM, under VirtualBox, and install the iTunes software under it. This is one of the main reasons why I did not want to buy any of the iPod series of devices, because Apple did not make iTunes to run under Linux.